# R: how to match partial string in one dataframe from another, and based on condition, assign a value?

Tags: r

OK - just as the title states, I'm trying to assign a value (in this case, male or female) to a column based on a partial match in another dataframe column.

I have a large database with customer names (db$customer) and a dataframe with 2000 of the most common boys and girls names (gender$name) and the gender (gender$gender). I'd like to, using a partial match, so something like

```
grepl()
```

,assign a value to the database dataframe (db$gender)

here is some quick reproducible code:

```
customer <- c("Smith, Mary", "Johnson, Jack", "Doe, Jane", "Bronson, Charles", "Huckstable,     Cliff", "Simpson, Jessica", "Simpson, Marge", "Mathews, Dave")
db <- as.data.frame(customer)
name <- c("Jack", "Charles", "Cliff", "Dave", "Mary", "Jane", "Jessica", "Marge")
gender <- c("M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F")
gender <- as.data.frame(cbind(name, gender))
```

Again, I'm looking to append the db file with a gender column indicating whether the customer name is a boy or girl's name.

Thank you so much for any all help! P.S. I searched the knowledge base, and maybe it's because I don't know what to really look for, could not find any existing help threads.

Thanks again!

Comment: You may also be able to achieve your desired coding using various gender-identifying tools including the [gender](https://github.com/ropensci/gender) package and the [gender-api.com API](https://gist.github.com/leeper/9021068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
db$gender <- sapply(db$customer,FUN=function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(gender)){
    if (grepl(gender$name[i],x)){
      return(gender$gender[i])
    } 
  }
  return(NA)
})
```

Comment: This does do what I want - however, it's very memory intensive... But I can't complain about 10 minutes of processing for a huge task that would take a day to do by hand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another direction, but it is incomplete.  It uses the `name2sex` function of the `qdap` package.  However, I am not sure how to satisfy the database argument.

```
require(qdap)
db$customer <- as.character(db$customer)
first.names <- sapply(strsplit(db$customer, split = ","), "[", 2) # to get the first name only
first.names <- unlist(strip(first.names)) # to trim leading and trailing spaces, etc.
name2sex(names.list = first.names, database = qdapDictionaries::NAMES_SEX) # needs more
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first names in `gender` and `db` are exact matches, we can use `merge` after splitting the customer names into first and last names.

```
db2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(db$customer), ", +")))

merge(db2, gender, by.x="X2", by.y="name", all.x=TRUE)

       X2         X1 gender
1 Charles    Bronson      M
2   Cliff Huckstable      M
3    Dave    Mathews      M
4    Jack    Johnson      M
5    Jane        Doe      F
6 Jessica    Simpson      F
7   Marge    Simpson      F
8    Mary      Smith      F
```

I have the "+" in `", +"` in the `strsplit` call because of the multiple spaces in 
`"Huckstable,     Cliff"`.  It is otherwise unnecessary.